# Pandas: selecting dates that are multiples of a day frequency in a grouped dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to make a very specific selection in a DataFrame containing dates. I have a "Lead Time" column that contains an integer, and I need to select every X dates that correspond to this integer in the DataFrame. For example: 
select row with every 15 days in date_range('2019-05-01', '2019-07-01') for each group. Here is a sample code of what I need to do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ITEM': ['A', 'B', 'C'] * 3, 'GROUP': [i+1 for i in range(3) for _ in range(3)],
                    'MONTH': [i+1 for i in range(3) for _ in range(3)],
                   'LEAD_TIME': [i for i in [15, 20, 10] for _ in range(3)]})
months = 2
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01')
dates = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': pd.date_range(start_date, start_date + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(months + 1), closed="left")})
dates['MONTH'] = dates['DATE'].dt.month
df = df.merge(dates, on='MONTH')

# df.loc[every LEAD_TIME days after start_date, 'check'] = True
```

Comment: could you give sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Inefficient solution

For each value in LEAD_TIME column You could get the values in the following way:

```
init_date = '2019-05-01'
div_res = pd.to_datetime(init_date).dayofyear % lead_time

df['day_of_year'] = df.DATE.apply(lambda x: x.dayofyear)
df['day_of_year_div_ts'] = df.day_of_year.apply(lambda x: x%lead_time)
result_dates = df.DATE[df.day_of_year_div_ts==div_res].tolist()
```

You can generalize it by making a function out of it and using `.apply()` to a dataframe target column.

### Elegant solution

```
lead_time = 15
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2019-10-01')
result_dates = pd.date_range(start = start_date, end = end_date, freq=pd.DateOffset(lead_time))
```

Comment: It doesn't help with date ranges that start with broken dates like 2019-03-12, for example. But this helped me figure out I just needed to use the index for each group and calculate the index % lead_time, so I will give it a right answer!

Comment: I probably get it wrong, but  2019-03-12 works for me. What do You mean by "broken dates"? Will be happy to fix it.

Comment: Well, when I had start_date = 2019-03-12, dayofyear at 2019-03-22, it would consider it as day 80, and when modulated by a lead_time of 40, it would consider it a True date, but in reality it is the tenth date of the series. I had to consider the first date of the range as the day 1, so I just used the index+1 % lead_time instead

Comment: I am glad, You have found the answer helpful! I think it is the issue of indexing, which can be solved depending on the accepted conventions.